# The Password between server & client is being passed in clear text

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, sniffing

The password between server & client is being passed in clear text when SSL is already activated. The security tester is saying that, the password can be seen in network layer. Where, it is secured in the application layer due to SSL. 
can any one help me regarding this issue??

Comment: Is tester trying man in the middle attack?

Comment: Without information on how you've implemented the SSL (and specifically how you've ensured that the login page and login action use HTTPS), you won't get any real answers.

Comment: This the configuration made in server.xml...

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this use digest auth
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication

Read e.g. Spring solutions
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/basic.html
http://www.jpalomaki.fi/?p=190
http://www.tinhtruong.me/2011/10/spring-security-with-digest.html